# Divide a dict by a number (int)

Tags: python, dictionary, int, counter, divide

i have a problem, i have to create a fuction that divide my dict by a int.
This is my dict:

```
Counter({1: [9, 10, 1], 2: [5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1], 0: [1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 10, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]})
```

And this is my function:

```
def probabilitacondizionata(lista, sommafreq):
    lista= {k: v / sommafreq for k, v in lista.items()}
    return lista
```

And this is the function, which sum the value(int) sommafreq:

```
def sommafrequenze(lista):
    sommafreq= sum(lista.values())
    return sommafreq
```

This instruction gives me this error: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict_values' and 'int' ..

The output i would is like:

```
Counter({1: [9/sommafreq, 10/sommafreq, 1/sommafreq], 2: [5/sommafreq, 1sommafreq, 1/sommafreq, 2/sommafreq, 1/sommafreq, 1/sommafreq, 9, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1], 0: [1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 10, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]})
```

and keep on going to divide all.. Sorry for my bad english and thanks in advance!

Edit: My previous functions:

```
def ricercafrequenze(trainspam, testspam):
    filtratespam=Counter()
    filtratespam ={k:v for (k,v) in trainspam.items() if k in testspam}

    return filtratespam
    #main
def ricerchefrequenzeinlista(lista1,lista2):
    lista=Counter()
    i=0
    while i < len(lista2):
       lista[i]=(ricercafrequenze(lista1, lista2[i]))
       i+=1
    return lista

Counter({0: {'offer': 1, 'time': 5, 'discount': 1, 'one': 1, 'th': 2, 'subject': 10, 'special': 1, 'need': 2, 'price': 1, 'order': 2, 'product': 2, 'per': 1, 'today': 1}, 1: {'us': 9, 'subject': 10, 'buy': 1}, 2: {'time': 5, 'realist': 1, 'quickli': 1, 'give': 2, 'go': 1, 'thoma': 1, 'us': 9, 'let': 1, 'aruba': 1, 'natur': 1, 'b': 3, 'length': 1, 'ca': 1, 'one': 1, 'know': 2, 'life': 1, 'think': 1, 'girlfriend': 1, 'use': 2, 'stronger': 1, 'press': 1, 'longer': 1, 'fl': 1, 'po': 1, 'partner': 1, 'subject': 10, 'presid': 1, 'save': 1, 'nearli': 1, 'stud': 1, 'short': 1, 'everi': 3, 'gain': 1, 'citi': 1, 'product': 2, 'said': 1, 'increas': 1, 'month': 1, 'unit': 3, 'want': 4, 'must': 1, 'sex': 1, 'pleasur': 1, 'result': 3, 'matt': 1, 'name': 4, 'love': 1, 'bigger': 1, 'visitor': 1, 'oranjestad': 1}})
```

Comment: Why don't you just divide the sum instead? You need to divide each item within the list: `{k: [x / sommafreq for x in v] for ... }`, but your current code shouldn't give the error you claim. Can you provide a [mcve] with full traceback?

Comment: thanks but, i gives me this error: AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: That's not a problem with my suggestion,;`lista` is apparently the values of the dictionary, not the dictionary itself.

Answer (score 1):

If `sommafrequenze` function is dedicated to sum up the values of the initial list - use the following simplified approach:

```
def probabilitacondizionata(lista, sommafreq):
    lista = {k: [v / sommafreq for v in v] for k, v in lista.items()}
    return lista

l = {1: [9, 10, 1], 2: [5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1], 0: [1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 10, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]}
l_sum = sum(v for sublist in l.values() for v in sublist)

print(probabilitacondizionata(l, l_sum))
```

The output:

```
{0: [0.007194244604316547, 0.03597122302158273, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.014388489208633094, 0.07194244604316546, 0.007194244604316547, 0.014388489208633094, 0.007194244604316547, 0.014388489208633094, 0.014388489208633094, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547], 1: [0.06474820143884892, 0.07194244604316546, 0.007194244604316547], 2: [0.03597122302158273, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.014388489208633094, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.06474820143884892, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.02158273381294964, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.014388489208633094, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.014388489208633094, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.07194244604316546, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.02158273381294964, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.014388489208633094, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.02158273381294964, 0.02877697841726619, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.02158273381294964, 0.007194244604316547, 0.02877697841726619, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547, 0.007194244604316547]}
```

Comment: thanks but always the same problem,  File "C:/Users/david/prova.py", line 141, in probabilitacondizionata
    {k: [v / sommafreq for v in v] for k, v in lista.items()}

AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: you have shown your dict as `Counter` argument, can you show the initial dict in its actual form ? Compare your dict with that one in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities:

<strike>1. Use `numpy` (as you have dicts as lista values, this is not applicable):</strike>

```
    import numpy as np
    def probabilitacondizionata(lista, sommafreq):
        lista= {k: np.array(list(v)) / sommafreq for k, v in lista.items()}
        return lista
```

2. Use **dict** comprehension:

```
    def probabilitacondizionata(lista, sommafreq):
        lista= {k: {k_i: v_i / sommafreq for k_i, v_i in v.items()} for k, v in lista.items()}
        return lista
```

Comment: Thanks for the two solutions , i tried the first: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict_values' and 'int'   and the second but,  
it gives me this error: AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'items' –

Comment: That's due to usi.ng Python 3. Try to wrap `v` in a list, as in the edit

Comment: It gives me the same error, AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'items'.. But is a counter not a dict.. can be this the problem?

Comment: The error says that `lista` is of type `dict_values` (and hence is not a dict). The error you are getting is because you are calling `probabilitacondizionata` having not a dict, but its values as a parameter

Comment: i discovered that is a <class 'collections.Counter'> my lista

Comment: Ok, then your `lista` has dicts as values, and not lists as you wrote originally. Then it explains everything, and you need not a list, but a dict comprehension.

Comment: how can i do it? the previous wasn't? was a list comprehension?

Comment: Where? But below they post me a dict comprehension but it doesn't work.. Can i convert this dict a list?

Comment: thanks, but always the same error 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'items'

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you can just evaluate the sum and then divide by a value to achieve the same thing. Anyways, you can divide every element like this:

```
Counter({k:[i/sommafreq for i in v] for k,v in lista.items()})
```

Comment: thanks but, i gives me this error: AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'items' –

Comment: @ErikGodard, no python 2 also has items(), so this is not a python 2/3 issue. May be OP is applying `.items()` on a list.

Comment: No i use python version 3.5 :(

Comment: Can be the problem the type of sommafreq? it is a int

Comment: @DavideDiMenna, No I have tested it with int value, and this is fine. Problem is in your side. Could you show us the output of `print type(lista)`?

Answer (score 0):

I often wanted to do this type of thing without using dict comprehensions. [BetterDict](https://github.com/Lguyogiro/BetterDict) is a little project of mine that extends Python dicts/Counters/defaultdicts/OrderedDicts, allowing them to be merged, or used in arithmetic with scalars or other dicts. 
eg

```
>>> raw_counts = BetterDict({'the': 1432, 'she': 600, 'wookie': 25})
>>> total = 10000.
>>> relative_freqs = raw_counts / total
>>> print(relative_freqs)
{'she': 0.06, 'the': 0.1432, 'wookie': 0.0025}
```